# Multiple submitform in update form in yii2

Tags: yii2

In my Update form, I have two submitform 'Save', 'Save & Submit'. each of them will update particular field.

The submit button looks like -

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Save',['name'=>'submit', 'value' => 'tello','class' =>  'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                <?= Html::submitButton('Save & Submit',['name'=>'submit', 'value' => 'hello','class' =>  'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

The best possible Controller Action I got so far is -

```
if(Yii::$app->request->post('submit')==='tello'){
            var_dump("Save is clicked");
            die();
       }
       elseif(Yii::$app->request->post('submit')==='hello'){
            var_dump("Submit is clicked");
            die();
       }
```

The problem with this is that, I have to click the button twice to submit it. I learned that I have to change the button name to anything but `submit`. I tried changing it anything else, but it didn't work. It's negelecting the code and proceeds to the next set of code.

I have this two button in create form as well

form

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Save',['name'=>'Save', 'value' => 'Save','class' =>  'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                <?= Html::submitButton('Save & Submit',['name'=>'Submit', 'value' => 'Submit','class' =>  'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

Controller action

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& isset($_POST['Save'])){
//do my stuff
}
elseif ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& isset($_POST['Submit'])){
//do my stuff
}
```

As asked by scaiseEdge Create Controller Action

```
public function actionCreatenewworkbasic()
    {
       $model = new Workpermit();

       //$model->wp_validfrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       //$model->wp_validto = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       $model->wp_timeissued = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

       if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && isset($_POST['Save'])) {

           //get the instance of the uploaded file
           //$jhaName = $model->wp_no;
           $model->wp_status = 'Saved';
           $timenow = date('-Y-m-d-H-i-s');
           $model->jha = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'jha');

           if (!empty($model->jha)) {

           $model->jha->saveAs('uploads/jha/'.$model->jha->baseName.$timenow.'.'.$model->jha->extension);      
           //save the path in the db
           $model->wp_jhaattach = 'uploads/jha/'.$model->jha->baseName.$timenow.'.'.$model->jha->extension;

           }                               
           $model->jha = null;
           $model->save(false);


            return $this->redirect(['availablework']); 
       }

       elseif ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
       {
           //get the instance of the uploaded file
           //$jhaName = $model->wp_no;
           $model->wp_status = 'Submitted';
           $timenow = date('-Y-m-d-H-i-s');
           $model->jha = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'jha');

           if (!empty($model->jha)) {

           $model->jha->saveAs('uploads/jha/'.$model->jha->baseName.$timenow.'.'.$model->jha->extension);      
           //save the path in the db
           $model->wp_jhaattach = 'uploads/jha/'.$model->jha->baseName.$timenow.'.'.$model->jha->extension;

           }                               
           $model->jha = null;
           $model->save(false);

           return $this->redirect(['availablework']); 
       }
       else{
            return $this->renderAjax('createnewworkbasic', [
               'model' => $model,
            ]);
       } 


    }
```

Action Update

```
public function actionUpdatenewwork($id)
    {
       $anotherchecklistitems = Anotherclreq::find()->select('acl_clname')->where(['acl_wpno'=>$id])->column();


       $anotherpermitlistitems = Anotherpermitreq::find()->select('apr_apname')->where(['apr_wpno'=>$id])->column();

       $model = $this->findModel($id);
       //we have a relation between workpermit and anotherchecklist named anotherchecklistrel
       $modelsAnotherchecklist = $model->anotherchecklistrel;
       $modelsAnotherpermitlist = $model->anotherpermitlistrel;

       if(isset($_POST['Workpermit']['anotherchecklist'])){

          $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsAnotherchecklist, 'acl_id', 'acl_id');
          $oldIDstring = implode(",", $oldIDs);

          // print_r($oldIDstring);
          // die();

          foreach ($oldIDs as $id) {
            Anotherclreq::findOne($id)->delete();
          }
          //die();

          $anotherChecklist = $_POST['Workpermit']['anotherchecklist'];
          foreach ($anotherChecklist as $value) {

            $anotherclreq = new Anotherclreq();
            $anotherclreq->acl_wpno = $model->wp_no;
            $anotherclreq->acl_clname = $value;
            $anotherclreq->save();

          }

       }

       if(isset($_POST['Workpermit']['anotherpermittype'])){

          $oldAPs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsAnotherpermitlist, 'apr_id', 'apr_id');
          $oldAPstring = implode(",", $oldAPs);
          // print_r($oldIDstring);
          // die();

          foreach ($oldAPs as $id) {
            Anotherpermitreq::findOne($id)->delete();
          }

          $anotherPermit = $_POST['Workpermit']['anotherpermittype'];
          foreach ($anotherPermit as $value) {

          $anotherpermitreq = new Anotherpermitreq();
          $anotherpermitreq->apr_wpno = $model->wp_no;
          $anotherpermitreq->apr_apname = $value;
          $anotherpermitreq->save();

          }

       }

       if(Yii::$app->request->post('submit')==='tello'){
            var_dump("Save is clicked");
            die();
       }
       elseif(Yii::$app->request->post('submit')==='hello'){
            var_dump("Submit is clicked");
            die();
       }

       if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
           //$model->wp_nwopcheckliststatus = 'Submitted';
           $model->save();
           return $this->redirect(['viewall', 'id' => $model->wp_no]);
       }

       return $this->render('updatenewwork', [
           'model' => $model,         
           'anotherchecklistitems' => $anotherchecklistitems,
           'anotherpermitlistitems' => $anotherpermitlistitems,
           ]);
    }
```

In the create form it works good. But for the update form it doesn't. Please help.

Some Observation - 
I've changed the buttons like below -

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Save',['id' => 'savename','name'=>'savename', 'value' => 'savename','class' =>  'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                <?= Html::submitButton('Save & Submit',['id' => 'submitname','name'=>'submitname', 'value' => 'submitname','class' =>  'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

Now If I use the following code in Controller action, the form is submitting as it should -

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {

           if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
              $model->wp_nwopcheckliststatus = 'Saved';
              $model->save();          
              return $this->redirect(['viewall', 'id' => $model->wp_no]);
           }
        }
```

But as soon as I change `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` to `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post('savename'))` it stops working.

Comment: Don't access directly to $_POST variable, you have all your post value into Yii::$app->request->post() [Read](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests)

Comment: update your question and show the code for action create and action update  ..  and the code for view create and view update

Comment: Sffili_81, thanks for the link. It's quite helpful link. scaisEdge, I've added the Controller Action for Create and Update. But the forms you asked for are too large.

Comment: what i understand you are trying to submit the **same form** with **2 different buttons** and to **2 different actions** inside the `controller`, your best bet is to use ajax to submit your form to 2 different actions, and you have to change the `buttonType` from `submit` to a `button` changing the `name` attribute wont make a difference, they would still submit to the same action the form is pointing.

Comment: I've a field wp_staus in model... During create I don't want to touch it. It'll have by default status NA. On update form I want to have two buttons. The Save button will write 'Saved' in it. and the 'Save and Submit' button will write 'Submit' in it. I thought, I can do it via controller action only.

Comment: I've updated the question with some observation.

Comment: `$model->load()` expects array with POST/GET data, while `Yii::$app->request->post('savename')` will return scalar in your case - it is not a surprise that it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create a hidden text field.

and instead of directly submitting the form, I would have attached an event listener.

meaning by javascript, add on click event on the buttons and change the value of hidden text field to anything - 0 - 1 or anything. and then submit the form.

for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pressed" id="pressed" />
<script>

$('#save').click(function(){
  $('pressed').val("save");
});   

$('#save-and-submit').click(function(){
  $('pressed').val("submit");
}); 

</script>
```

then check in `$_POST['pressed'];`